# Regex ignore special character with greedy

Tags: regex

I used the following regex to catch 10 numbers and letters:

`/[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}/g`

It works fine if the 10 characters are only numbers and letters.

> e.g. input: `12345xcdw034342`
> it catches `12345xcdw0`

But in this case with special characters or space, it doesn't catch it.
`123}456712234324Zz3` or `123}45 71223AB3`

It should catch 10 numbers and letters regardness of characters.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Not quite clear what you are looking for. You want the space and all special characters to be part of the 10-digit match?

Comment: nah~ not part of the 10 digit match. 
e.g. 123456789@0
then it should match 1234567890

Comment: So, are you using JavaScript? `nsregularexpression` is a class in the Swift programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but not without any extra processing

As you have not spetified what language you're using Ill use Javascript for being quite universal but the same logic must apply in any language.

Here are the options I can think of

if I have `testString = "12@34{56A789BDE"`

1. Match the all until the first ten alphanumeric caracters, and then remove the spetial characters in the resulting string

```
testString.match(/(\w.*?){10}/)[0].replaceAll(/\W/g, '')
// results '123456A789'
// explanation: we take the first \w and use .*? to indicate that we dont care if the alphanumeric has a non-alphanumeric right next to it, then we clean the result by removing \W which means non-alphanumeric
```

2. Match only the first ten alphanumeric caracters and then join them to make a result string

```
testString.match(/\w/g).splice(0,10).join('')
// results '123456A789'
// explanation: we match 10 groups of aphanumeric characters represented by  \w (note the lowercase) and we join the first 10 (using splice to get them) as each group "()" is in the case of javascript returned as an element of an array of matches
```

3. Remove the spetial characters from your string and then take the first ten

```
testString.replaceAll(/\W/g,'').match(/\w{10}/)[0]
// results '123456A789'
// explanation:  we replace \W which means non alpha numeric characters, with '' to delete them then we match the first ten
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
/[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){9}/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YoAopd/1). *Details*:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - an alphanumeric
- `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9]){9}` - nine occurrences of any zero or more chars other than an alphanumeric char and then an alphanumeric char.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know how only alpahnumeric matches. for example, I have a string 123456%7890123. Then it should match 1234567890.

Comment: @Danny This is impossible, regex never and nowhere works like that. So, 1) first match, then 2) remove the redundant non-alphanumerics from the matches. If you need more help, please mention your programming language.